# Python django packages not installing

Tags: django, django-import-export

When I run an "pip install" it works and the package installs. Here is an example for the import-export package:

```
Installing collected packages: xlrd, pyyaml, xlwt, unicodecsv, jdcal, et-xmlfile, openpyxl, defusedxml, odfpy, tablib, diff-match-patch, django-import-export
Successfully installed defusedxml-0.5.0 diff-match-patch-20181111 django-import-export-1.2.0 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 jdcal-1.4 odfpy-1.4.0 openpyxl-2.6.0 pyyaml-3.13 tablib-0.12.1 unicodecsv-0.14.1 xlrd-1.2.0 xlwt-1.3.0
```

but when I try to run the app with the package, I get this error:

```
  File "~/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import-export'
```

I have added 'import-export' to my apps. This error occurs when I run "python3 manage.py collectstatic".

Comment: did you run pip install in the right virtual environment?

Comment: also, what django version do you have?

Comment: Yes, I pip installed in my project directory and Django version 2.1.7

Comment: But, my package is in another folder with python.

Comment: can you run `which python` command and check which python version is default for you evironment?

Answer (score 1):

If "I have added 'import-export' to my apps." means

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'import_export',
)
```

it may be

```
import import_export
```

no hyphen, it is underbar

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `"Django-import-export"`.

In your settings.py you must add the following.

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'import_export',
)
```

and then use `$ manage.py collectstatic`

For more information read this [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-and-configuration)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did and that's the error that i got. I followed the documentation.